# How can I make multiplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I have this dataset, I want to make triple y axis where "Country" will be X axis. in the y axis I want to do two clustered column with one line graph overlapping.
I am a new user, learning for 16 days

```
dput(data)

structure(list(Country = c("China", "Indonesia", "Vietnam", "Thailand", 
"Egypt", "India", "Turkey", "Brazil", "United States", "Russia"
), Plastic.Consumption = c(44.14201935, 12.87658986, 23.6336878, 
52.92058216, 13.93164324, 6.994354455, 64.77526757, 31.53076177, 
87.30070657, 32.01972449), Plastic.Production.Kt. = c(42421L, 
2258L, 387L, 5881L, 411L, 7211L, 939L, 5860L, 33985L, 3487L), 
    Plastic.Waste.Mismanagemet..kt. = c(8819.716784, 3216.855605, 
    1833.819141, 1027.739178, 967.0123574, 599.8191155, 485.937142, 
    471.4039969, 275.4244968, 80.75948103)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here is a resource that demonstrates why two Y axis are a bad idea [link](https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/). Here are some examples of other options.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Country = c("China", "Indonesia", "Vietnam", "Thailand", 
                           "Egypt", "India", "Turkey", "Brazil", "United States", "Russia"
), Plastic.Consumption = c(44.14201935, 12.87658986, 23.6336878, 
                           52.92058216, 13.93164324, 6.994354455, 64.77526757, 31.53076177, 
                           87.30070657, 32.01972449), Plastic.Production.Kt. = c(42421L, 
                                                                                 2258L, 387L, 5881L, 411L, 7211L, 939L, 5860L, 33985L, 3487L), 
Plastic.Waste.Mismanagemet..kt. = c(8819.716784, 3216.855605, 
                                    1833.819141, 1027.739178, 967.0123574, 599.8191155, 485.937142, 
                                    471.4039969, 275.4244968, 80.75948103)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -10L))

ggplot(df,aes(Country,Plastic.Consumption,size = Plastic.Waste.Mismanagemet..kt.,color = Plastic.Waste.Mismanagemet..kt.)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(2:4) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Country,value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~name,scales = 'free')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Warnings about using secondary axes notwithstanding, here is how you can create the plot you describe from the data you shared:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(Country = forcats::fct_reorder(Country, -Plastic.Production.Kt.)) %>%
  pivot_longer(3:4) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Country, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Plastic.Consumption * 400, group = 1, 
                color = "Consumption"), size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "black", name = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "deepskyblue4"), name = "",
                    labels = c("Plastic production", 
                               "Plastic waste mismanagement")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma, name = "kilotonnes per year",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ .x/400, 
                                         name = "Consumption (kilotonnes)")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, Thank you very much it was a great help, i am just curious that why you multiply plastic consumption by 400? (geom_line(aes(y = Plastic.Consumption * 400, group = 1) and if I want to Make Production and consumption in column and mismanagement in line plot i can use that code by replacing the variables?

Comment: @Kazi if you want to show variables in a single plot where the numbers are on such different scales, you need to multiply one of the variables by some constant to get it into approximately the same range as the others, but then create a second axis whose numbers are multiplied by the inverse of the same constant. In your example this allows you to read the bars from the left axis, but the line from the right axis. You can't just swap variables because the scales are so different. Your production numbers are about 500 times larger than the consumption, so the bars can't be displayed together